# typescript conditional type on enum key

Tags: typescript, conditional-statements, typescript-typings

I though this was very straightforward bu apparently I was wrong. How can I create a simple conditional type based on an enum key? like this:

```
export enum inputTypes {
  text = 'text',
  email = 'email',
  password = 'password',
  number = 'number',
  date = 'date',
  textarea = 'textarea',
  dropdown = 'dropdown',
  checkbox = 'checkbox',
}

export interface IInput {
  id: string,
  type: inputTypes,
  name: string,
}
```

And the conditional type based on the inputType:

```
export type onInputChange =
IInput['type'] extends inputTypes.dropdown
? DropDownChangeEventHandler
: FormChangeEventHandler;
```

I've tried some variations with `keyof` `typeof` `keyof typeof` And could not reach what I am trying.

The end result that I need is that if the input type is dropdown I'd like to have a different change event. So my `type onInputChange` would be equal to: `DropDownChangeEventHandler | FormChangeEventHandler`, and later in the code, do a type guard and get the proper type for the dropdown change event.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to compute the `onInputChange` type at runtime, which is not possible with TypeScript.

Comment: no, I'am not. I'm doing a typeguard in my code. I expect the type to be `DropDownChangeEventHandler | FormChangeEventHandler`

Comment: Why not declare it as such? You could potentially use a discriminated union to get compile type checking, but `IInput['type'] extends inputTypes.dropdown` is a compile-time check that will only run once.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I correctly understood what you're trying to do, but I think the issue might be with your condition on `onInputChange` type:

```
export type onInputChange =
   IInput['type'] extends inputTypes.dropdown
   ? DropDownChangeEventHandler
   : FormChangeEventHandler;
```

What you're saying here is: if the type of property `type` on `IInput` interface extends `'dropdown'` give me type `DropDownChangeEventHandler` else give me type `FormChangeEventHandler`.

The point is that condition will never be true, as you defined `type` on `IInput` as `inputTypes`. Enum types define a union of each enum member and `'foo' | 'bar' extends 'foo'` will always be false.

I guess, what you actually want to check in your condition is not the type of `type` property on `IInput` interface, but the type of `type` property *on a specific implementation* of that interface. Obviously that information is only available once you implemented the interface.

A way to do this is probably using generics:

```
export type onInputChange<T> =
    T extends inputTypes.dropdown
    ? DropDownChangeEventHandler
    : FormChangeEventHandler;

export class Test implements IInput {
    id: string;
    type: inputTypes.dropdown;
    name: string;
    onChange: onInputChange<Test['type']>;    
}
```

Comment: Like your solution, I'll try it in a minute